# In Notepad++/Sublime Text 3, how do I make all text lowercase by regex, but only if specific phrase occured in the line?

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3, text-processing

Say I have text like that:

```
models/players/clonespac/CloneTorsoLieutenant
{
    q3map_nolightmap
    q3map_onlyvertexlighting
    {
        map models/players/clonespac/CloneTorsoLieutenant
        blendFunc GL_ONE GL_ZERO
        rgbGen lightingDiffuse
    }
    {
        map gfx/effects/clone
        blendFunc GL_DST_COLOR GL_SRC_COLOR
        tcGen environment
        blendFunc GL_SRC_ALPHA GL_ONE
        detail
        alphaGen lightingSpecular
    }
}
```

and I want to **convert all letters to lowercase, but only if the line contains the word** "models".

Resulting in this:

```
models/players/clonespac/clonetorsolieutenant
{
    q3map_nolightmap
    q3map_onlyvertexlighting
    {
        map models/players/clonespac/clonetorsolieutenant
        blendFunc GL_ONE GL_ZERO
        rgbGen lightingDiffuse
    }
    {
        map gfx/effects/clone
        blendFunc GL_DST_COLOR GL_SRC_COLOR
        tcGen environment
        blendFunc GL_SRC_ALPHA GL_ONE
        detail
        alphaGen lightingSpecular
    }
}
```

I know I can do this:
`(\w)` -> `\L$1` but it replaces every character.

I tried doing it like that:

`models (\w)` -> `models \L$1` but any attempts like that are failing.

Comment: @Gantendo It is fully on topic as long as it concerns specific software, I don't know what makes you think otherwise, questions like that appear literally at least few times a week. It's quite low effort but not a duplicate from what I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
^.*?[Mm]odels.*?$
```

Explantation:

- `^` - match start of the line
- `.*?` - anything, non-greedy, after and before the word you're looking for
- `[Mm]odels` - case insensitive `models`. Wrap it in `\b`s to ensure that e.g. `someothermodels` isn't matched.
- `$` - end of line

Then replace with:

```
\L$0
```

which in Boost regex engine used by Notepad++/Sublime Text 3 means that `\L` will lowercase anything after it and `$0` is full match, so entire matching lines.